# 5 books in 3 bundles

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

5 distinct books can be tied in 3 indistinct bundles in how many ways, if order of book within a bundle does not matter?

I have counted in following way, and I saw another person counting in a different way, which also seem correct to me, but our results do not tally. Can anyone point out why?

My way :

$5$ books can be tied in $3$ bundles in two different ways 1 + 1 + 3 or 1+2+2.

$1+1+3\rightarrow \binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways

$1+2+2\rightarrow \binom{5}{1} \binom{4}{2}=5.6=30$ ways.

Total 10+30 = 40 ways.

Another person's way :

5 distinct books can be divided in 3 distinct bundles (empty allowed) in $3^5$ ways. Subtracting the cases where one bundle is empty  $\binom{3}{1} 2^5$, adding the cases where 2 bundles are empty $\binom{3}{1} 1^5$. Total $3^5-3.2^5+3=243-96+3=150$. Since the bundles are indistinguishable, all 3! permutations among the bundles are to be counted only once. So total number of ways = $150/6=25$

Comment: For your $1+2+2$ case you chose $\binom{4}{2}$ instead of $\binom{3}{2}$.  Why?

Comment: When you choose $2$ on $\binom{4}{2}$ you are marking the bundle in some sense, you should, then divide by $2$ to take out the "distinction".

Comment: 4 books left to choose in one of the 2-bundles, after 1 book is chosen for 1-bundle.

Comment: As an aside, the solution to the generalization of this problem with $n$ distinct books and $k$ unlabeled non-empty bundles is given by the [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) ${n\brace k}$.  Here, [${5 \brace 3} = 25$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=stirlingS2%5B5%2C3%5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your $1+2+2$ case.

You begin by choosing the one book that gets bundled by itself.  This can be accomplished in $5$ ways.

The next step, in presumably what you are thinking, is to "pick which two books go into the **first** 2-bundle" and then the remaining books go into the **second** 2-bundle.  This can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.

However... *we can't tell after the fact which of the two 2-bundles was the "first" or the "second"!*  You have double counted these outcomes.

You can correct this by recognizing that you counted each outcome twice and dividing by symmetry... giving $\binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=15$ ways for this case.

I dislike "division by symmetry arguments" and so instead prefer to think of this as after having chosen the book for the 1-bundle, *among those four remaining books one has the smallest ISBN number* (*or other distinguishable feature*).  We then choose which book gets paired with that book.  The remaining books get paired together.  Choosing which book gets paired with that book with the smallest ISBN number can be done in $3$ ways, giving a total of $5\cdot 3 = 15$ ways for this case.

Comment: Why don't you like symmetry arguments?

Comment: @mjw they require division, an operation which does not need to have been formally defined at the point at which questions like this can be explored.  You can get along fine in combinatorics using exclusively addition, subtraction, and multiplication.  Division of two integers could possibly result in a non-integer.  It is hard to justify in some cases without deeper analysis why some division operations in certain combinatorics problems still result in an integer.  Indeed, several incorrect approaches taken by beginner students can yield non-integer answers to counting problems.

Comment: Avoiding division by symmetry arguments, it is impossible to arrive at a non-integer answer to a counting problem.  Further, division by symmetry arguments are often non-intuitive for several beginning students.  I do not completely dismiss them, they are useful, however from experience I find they can for certain students cause unnecessary confusion in terms of when they are needed or how they are used.  Finally, I find arguments which avoid division by symmetry to be more "elegant."

Comment: Very interesting, and I understand your approach.  I would argue that if when dividing, the answer is not an integer, that gives a clear indication that a mistake was made, so if somebody at least has that minimal skill at error checking, it may actually be helpful to try a symmetry argument.  The other thing, and it is really a matter of taste, is that I find symmetry arguments to be elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you allow an empty bundle, then you can have the following situations:

A:  $\{5,0,0\}$.  There is one way to do this.

B:  $\{4,1,0\}$.  There are five ways to do this (select the one that is in its own bundle.

C:  $\{3,2,0\}$.  There are $\pmatrix{5\\3}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$ ways.

D:  $\{3,1,1\}$.  There are $\pmatrix{5\\3} = 10 $ ways.

E:  $\{2,2,1\}$.  There are $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \pmatrix{5\\2} \cdot \pmatrix{3\\2}=10\cdot 3 /2=15$ ways.

That is it.  Adding them up:  $1+5+10+10+15=41.$

The comments are correct!  We've got duplicates in E and need to divide by two.  (Bundle 1 and bundle 3 are exchangeable).

Comment: You made the same mistake as the OP

Comment: $\{\{A\},\{B,C\},\{D,E\}\} = \{\{A\},\{D,E\},\{B,C\}\}$.  Choose $A$ as the first.  Continuing and "*choosing two among four*" and choosing $B,C$ leads to the same final outcome as instead choosing $D,E$

Comment: Oh ... you are right!  Thank you!

Comment: "*Some have a problem with case E*"  You are correct... *some do*... you and OP chief among them.  In your notation above, compare the outcomes of `Bundle 1: {a,b} Bundle 2: {c}` and `Bundle 1: {d,e}, Bundle 2: {c}`.  Those are indistinguishable.

Comment: @JMoravitz, Right.  Am on your side now.  Thanks again!